# LINQ how to return last date and difference between first and last count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core

I have a table with the following column and sample data:

```
acteename   updated_at              count (count is not sorted in db)

dev-52      2/7/2020 5:56:43 PM     1
dev-52      2/7/2020 5:56:52 PM     2
dev-52      2/7/2020 5:57:00 PM     3
dev-52      2/7/2020 5:57:49 PM     4
dev-52      2/7/2020 5:59:19 PM     5
dev-52      2/7/2020 6:01:51 PM     6
dev-52      2/7/2020 6:06:21 PM     7
dev-52      2/7/2020 6:14:51 PM     8
dev-52      2/7/2020 6:31:23 PM     9
dev-52      2/7/2020 6:47:54 PM     10
dev-52      2/7/2020 7:04:26 PM     11
dev-52      2/7/2020 7:20:58 PM     12
```

I want to return diff between `first` and `last` count sorted by `updated_at` and last `updated_at` `where` `acteename` is equal to some name that I get from different table

```
IQueryable<Events> list = _DBcontext.Events.GroupBy(p => p.ActeeName)
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                acteename = g.Key,
                                lastupdated = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.UpdatedAt).First(),
                                firstcount = g.OrderBy(p => p.UpdatedAt).First().Count,
                                lastcount = g.OrderByDescending(p => p.UpdatedAt).First().Count
                            })
                            .Select(x => new { x.acteename,x.lastupdated, diff = x.lastcount - x.firstcount })
                            .Where(a => a.acteename == item.AppName)
                            .ToList();
```

Getting following Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string acteename,
>   TestApp.Models.Events lastupdated, int diff>>'` to
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<TestApp.Models.Events>'`. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

expected output:

```
dev-52      2/7/2020 7:20:58 PM     11
```

kinda stuck on this not sure if the LINQ query is correct or not, any help will be useful :)

Update:

Exact Query that I ran:

```
var list = from p in _DBcontext.AppProcessCrashEvents
                                   where p.Actee == item.AppGuid
                                   group p by p.Actee
            into gList
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       acteenamex = gList.Key,
                                       lastUpdated_at = gList.OrderBy(x => x.UpdatedAt).Last().UpdatedAt,
                                       diff = gList.OrderBy(x => x.UpdatedAt).Last().CrashCount -
                                                             gList.OrderBy(x => x.UpdatedAt).First().CrashCount
                                   };
```

Comment: Obviously `IQueryable<Events> != List<Events>`. Just change IQueryable to List and it will work.

Comment: @panoskarajohn you can't "just" do that as one can't have *explicit* declaration with anonymous type... `var` on other hand would be fine.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov correct.

Comment: Also, You might want to apply the `Where` clause first, to filter results before selecting, and then you only need one `Select` clause - just select the properties you want for the anonymous type in a single `Select` statement.

Comment: @RufusL what about `GroupBy`?

Comment: Should be : .Select(x => new { acteename = x.acteename, lastupdated = x.lastupdated, diff = x.lastcount - x.firstcount })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can apply the filter in very beginning itself. Use `group by` with `into` and then finally select what you need. Since its creating a anonymous object hence it would be better to start with 'var`.

**Edited:** Fetch the data in memory and then apply `group by` to avoid any problem in mapping with database side grouping.

```
var list =  (from p in _DBcontext.Events
            where p.acteename == item.AppName select p).ToList();

var fList = (from p in list 
            group p by p.acteename
            into gList
            select new
            {
               acteenamex = gList.Key,
               lastUpdated_at = gList.OrderBy(x => x.updated_at).Last().updated_at,
               diff = gList.OrderBy(x => x.updated_at).Last().count - 
                                      gList.OrderBy(x => x.updated_at).First().count
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Sam Lets break the query in two parts. `1) var list =  (from p in _DBcontext.Events where p.acteename == item.AppName).ToList();` and then apply `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list by the `AppGuid` first, then order it, and then convert that to list. Now, use this list in a new variable to get the records you need from it.

```
var gList = _DBcontext.AppProcessCrashEvents
        .Where(x => x.Actee == item.AppGuid)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.UpdatedAt)
        .ToList();

var result = new Events
{
    Actee = gList[0].Actee,
    UpdatedAt = gList[0].UpdatedAt,
    CrashCount = gList[0].CrashCount - gList[gList.Count - 1].CrashCount
};
```

I hope this is what are you looking for.